# iOS - embedding a viewController on a navigationController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I have 3 view controllers, `vcA`, `vcB` and `vcC`.

I am on `vcA` and push `vcB`. It works.

When I try to push `vcC` from `vcB`, it fails. I see that `self.navigationController` property of `vcB` is `nil`.

Reading the help file regarding to this property, I see this:

> This property is nil if the view controller is not embedded inside a navigation controller.

So, `vcB` is probably not inside the navigation controller.

My question is, is `self.navigationController pushViewController:vcB ...` enough to embed `vcB` on the navigation controller? If not, how do I embed `vcB` on the navigation controller?

NB: `vcA` is built on Interface Builder and `vcB` and `vcC` are created programmatically.

Comment: Can you post some code?  Conceptually it sounds like you've got it right.  I assume `vcA` is initially displayed by being pushed onto a navigation controller's view stack.

Comment: ok, but my question is this: I have vcA embedded on the navigation controller and this was done in interface builder. Now, how do I embed a second view controller (vcB) on the navigation controller? This vcB is created programmatically inside vcA.

Comment: yes you can push an other controller by using the method pushViewController, but show your code to see the problem were is it.

Comment: We really need to see the code.  How was `vcA` added to the navigation controller's view stack in the first place?  If you set a breakpoint somewhere in `vcA`, can you verify that its `self.navigationController` property is not nil?

Comment: This is the second time you've posted this same question -- you shouldn't do that. I will make the same comment I made on your other post. You need to show more code or post your entire project on github or somewhere else.

Comment: this is not the same question. This is how I embed a controller.

Comment: Well, it looks pretty similar to me, and my comment still stands -- the reason you're not getting an answer, is that you're not giving enough information. As I said before, if you push to vcB from vcA, then vcB should get embedded in a navigation controller -- if it's not, as you say, then you're doing something wrong, something which we cannot diagnose without more code.

Comment: You're not creating a property in vcB called navigationController are you?

Comment: no, I am not, but if I create and pass a reference of the navigationController using it, I can push vcC, but when I pop vcC, I get vcA!!! vcC returns to vcA when popped ????!!!!! WTF? I have tried to simplify the project to post to github but the simplified version works perfectly! I am trying to discover what did I remove that solved the problem!!!!!!!

Comment: If you do find it, remember to post your fix here so we'll know what happened. If you can't find it, I'd be glad to take a look at it privately if you can share it.

Comment: ok, I will post that, but it will take time to discover that.

Comment: I am still fighting to discover the problem. I did one change that was this: I have created a property on both vB and vC to forward self.navigationController. Now I can push B and C but when I pop C out, I go to A. I have printed to console the viewControllers property of self.navigationController before and after pushing vB and it contains just A. Or in other words: pushing B from A is not adding B to the self.navigationController stack!!! (what?) This is the problem. Don't ask me why.

Comment: @rdelmar I have finally discovered the problem. See my solution! Thanks for all your help. I had +1 you two times!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 days I finally solved this problem.

This problem is that the one of my viewControllers and the navigationController were **both** connected to the delegate's rootViewController outlet. **Thanks Xcode for not pointing that!** Sorry but I have to say again that I hate Xcode 4 now more than ever.

The solution for this problem, was related with another problem I had and can be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13280574/316469

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define your viewController int this way:

Define vcB in vcA

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *vcB;

@synthesize vcB = _vcB;
```

then push it on stack.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.vcB animated:YES];
```

Define vcC in vcB

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *vcC;

@synthesize vcC = _vcC;
```

then push it on stack.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.vcC animated:YES];
```

Comment: You don't need to maintain a strong reference to `vcB` (via a property) in `vcA` just for the sake of adding `vcB` to the navigation controller's view stack.